# Series with prime number second method

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Today I made an exercise in which I had to prove that :

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{p_n}
$$
where $p_n$ is a prime number ($p_1=2$) is divergent.

Well it was really difficult and at the end of the correction they say "the result is evident if we know that $p_n \sim \ln(n)$"

They don't precise anything more about we can obtain this equivalence, can you tell me the demonstration, I really have no idea ...

A hint is also apprieciate !

Thank you

Comment: It should be "$p_n \sim n\ln (n)$". For $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n},$$ you compare with an integral. By the limit comparison test, that series is convergent if and only if $\sum \frac{1}{p_n}$ is convergent.

Comment: it should say $p_n \sim n \log n$ which is equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem. Your exercise was earlier by some 30 years, Merten's second, which is genuinely easier.

Comment: does not matter much, Chebyshev had early, correct proofs that the ratio of $p_n$ and $n \log n$ is between certain constants, which is enough for divergence. That also predates the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: OK thanks I will try ! :)